# Adaptive Payments SDK payResponse error

Tags: php, paypal, sdk, paypal-sandbox

Does anyone know what this means? (below).  I have a website with personal payments/preapprovals.  When the receiver clicks a button to claim their funds from the preapproval, I get this error message.  I'm testing in Sandbox using a sender sandbox account, recipient is my email address (different from sandbox sender).  Help!

> payResponse: PayResponse Object ( [responseEnvelope] =>
>   ResponseEnvelope Object ( [timestamp] => 2015-12-09T00:13:39.067-08:00
>   [ack] => Failure [correlationId] => 95ec8c7adeb55 [build] => 17820627
>   ) [payKey] => [paymentExecStatus] => [payErrorList] =>
>   [defaultFundingPlan] => [warningDataList] => [error] => Array ( [0] =>
>   ErrorData Object ( [errorId] => 580023 [domain] => PLATFORM
>   [subdomain] => Application [severity] => Error [category] =>
>   Application [message] => The fee payer SENDER cannot be used with
>   unilateral receiver [exceptionId] => [parameter] => Array ( [0] =>
>   ErrorParameter Object ( [name] => [value] => SENDER ) ) ) ) )

Could not process payment. Please try again in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the SENDER as the party who handles the fee in Adaptive Payment Chained Payment. See [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/). Chained Payment won't allow the sender to pay all the fees.